# Remove specified digits from a String in java

Tags: java

I am trying to remove 1st 000 digits from given string like `0006700guys`.

I want to remove 0's from before the any decimal num started.

Suppose if my String contain `006700guys`, then i want to remove 1st two 0's, I need O/P like `6700guys`.

If my String contains `000006700chi` O/P like `6700chi`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Substring.....post some code that you have tried?

Comment: We're not gonna solve this for you, the format is that you share some code that you've tried and we help you with that. So have you tried anything?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String removeZeros(String original) {
    if (original == null) return null;
    int index=0;
    while (index<original.length() && original.charAt(index)=='0') index++;
    if (index==0) return original;
    return(original.substring(index));     
}
```

Comment: You program fails for 000 (only zeros)

Comment: +1, the fastest solution so far. Would be *really* nice to see a null check for `original` though and for the `substring` to only be called if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
while(s.startsWith("0")) {
    s = s.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered performance of your solution? I believe not.

Comment: Your program will create new objects until find non-zero char.

Comment: I know. But does it really matter? It is easy to read and might be efficient enough for what he wants to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

try regex

```
s = s.replaceAll("^0+(.+)", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

If `s` is your string then `s.split("^0*")[1]` will give you the required string.

Here, I'm using a *regular expression* string splitter. `^` means the start of the string and `*` means zero or more of the preceding element. `[1]` takes the first (zero based) element of the return (which will always contain exactly 2 elements, the proof of which I'll leave to the OP).

Answer (score 0):

Easy to read solution..anyway regex would be fast than this..

```
public static String removeLeadingZeros(String str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
    {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c != '0' && !Character.isSpaceChar(c))
            return str.substring(i);
    }
}
```